# Netbeans 8 slow opening PHP-Projects (Netbeans 7.3.x was ok)

Tags: php, performance, networking, netbeans

Today i updated my Netbeans IDE to the latest version 8.0.2. Until this update each project (PHP ... mostly Joomla, Magento, Zend, Wordpress, etc.) opened in notime. Now it takes somewhat about 10 minutes.

I'm running netbeans on a Win7 64bit. The problematic projects are stored on a networkdrive (shared SAMBA of an Ubuntu).

But this was also my environment for NB7.3.x So nothing changed here :(

Opening a project from the local (WIN7) filesystem is still fine.

Edit: Keep a synced version on the local filesystem and setup a SFTP to my Ubuntu (often mentioned solution according scanning-performance in Netbeans) is not a practicable way for me. For quite each project I have to keep/manage a connection to the server running the liveversion of the project. This would cause endless switching between dev-connection and live-connection within somewhat of 50+ possible connections managed within netbeans.

Comment: All my researches let me come to the conclusion that netbeans (at least the 8.x versions) needs to have the projects stored on a local hdd to work fast. Unfortunately it isn't able to handle deployment in an efficient way. Each time you have to switch the right remote connection (out of all managed connections in netbeans) in the preferences. Therefore I'm now going to use PHPStorm. Similar way but much more control over your connections and the ability to choose a connection right before deployment(And it seems to filter for the right remotes for each project). Sorry NB we had a great time.